# Google Cloud Appengine returns '404 Error' when calling Spring Boot REST APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a spring boot application to Google cloud appengine service. When I run the application locally using `mvn appengine:run` everything works fine and I'm able to send requests to REST APIs and get expected responses back. In fact when I deploy the application to appengine I can see the application logs which indicate that server is up and there aren't any exceptions or warnings during server initialization; But when I try to call any kind of endpoints, google send a HTML page containing below text:
**Error: Not Found**

I'm using:
JDK 1.8
Spring Boot 2.4.5
Maven
Cloud SDK version 395.0.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The version deployed June 30, 2022 runs without issues. The exact same code base deployed today gives 404 for all Spring Boot endpoints. Static files load fine. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the Cloud SDK since that's the only thing that has changed. I'm using: JDK-1.8, SB-2.3.11, Cloud SDK-395.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, this is a problem with the Cloud SDK v395.0.0. You can deploy your application using an older version by setting the cloudSdkVersion configuration parameter of the appengine maven plugin in your pom.xml file. More information can be found in the [AppEngine Maven Plugin reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md) document.

I tested this by deploying the Spring Boot helloWorld world sample app with various versions of the SDK and it broke once deployed with v395+

[This issue has been reported on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240455023)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. This is the exact problem. I had removed the line which specifies cloud SDK version from appengine-maven-plugin. I just added ```<cloudSdkVersion>330.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>``` to the appengine-maven-plugin configuration and everything works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the port. By default, 8080 is the default port. If you want to change the port. Follow below link

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#network_settings